# restore mysql database using java in linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux

i am a linux user i want to restore mysql database using java i use this code to backup it but i didn't find any working way to restore it. this code is for backup:

```
private static String ip = "localhost";
private static String port = "3306";
private static String database = "IMS";
private static String user = "root";
private static String pass = "pass";
private static String path = "/home/user/Desktop/project/";

    public static void backup() {
    Date dateNow = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateformatyyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String date_to_string = dateformatyyyyMMdd.format(dateNow);
    System.out.println("date into yyyyMMdd format: " + date_to_string);
    String ss = "IMS.sql";
    String fullName = path + " " + date_to_string + " " + ss;
    String dumpCommand = "mysqldump " + database + " -h " + ip + " -u " + user + " -p" + pass;
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    File test = new File(fullName);
    PrintStream ps;
    try {
        Process child = rt.exec(dumpCommand);
        ps = new PrintStream(test);
        InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            ps.write(ch);
        //System.out.write(ch); //to view it by console
        }

        InputStream err = child.getErrorStream();
        while ((ch = err.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.write(ch);
        }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String user = "root";
    String pass = "1234";
    String[] restoreCmd = new String[]{"mysql", "--user=" + user, "--password=" + pass, "-e", "source " + path};
    Process process;
    try {


 process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(restoreCmd);
        int procCom = process.waitFor();
        if (procCom == 0) {
            lbl_restore.setText("Restore Succes!");
        } else {
            lbl_restore.setText("Can't Restore!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
public boolean restoreDatabase(String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String source) {

    String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql", "--user=" + dbUserName, "--password=" + dbPassword, "-e", "source " + source};

    Process runtimeProcess;

    try {
        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            log.info("Backup restored successfully with " + source);
            return true;
        } else {
            log.info("Could not restore the backup " + source);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex, ex.getCause());
    }

    return false;
}
```